# Make a copy of the printed Word document and save it in a folder

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need a to create a macro on my Word which would save the printed document automatically to another location on my computer. I have looked through hundreds of options online and here also but couldn't exactly what I was looking for. Saving it to another location is easy but it should make a copy only when the the document is in the print queue. Can anyone help me out here? Need it for my employee monitoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Application.DocumentBeforePrint event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.documentbeforeprint) which is triggered everytime before the opened document is printed.

The following code needs to be placed in a *class module*, and an instance of the class must be correctly initialized.

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents App as Word.Application 

Private Sub App_DocumentBeforePrint(ByVal Doc As Document, ByRef Cancel As Boolean)   
     Doc.SaveAs2 FileName:="your path"
End Sub
```

*<sup>Code 1: Put this code into a class module called "EventClassModule".</sup>*

According to [Using events with the Application object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/objects-properties-methods/using-events-with-the-application-object-word) you need to register the event handler before it will work.

```
Option Explicit

Dim ThisWordApp As New EventClassModule

Public Sub RegisterEventHandler()
    Set ThisWordApp.App = Word.Application
End Sub
```

*<sup>Code 2: Put this code into a normal module (not a class module).</sup>*

The event `DocumentBeforePrint` will work after you registered the event handler by running `RegisterEventHandler`, this is recommended to run whenever the document is opened. Therefore we use the [Document.Open event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.open) in `ThisDocument`:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Document_Open()
    RegisterEventHandler
End Sub
```

*<sup>Code 3: Put this code into "ThisDocument".</sup>*

Then save, close and re-open your document. If you print it now, the event `DocumentBeforePrint` will execute right before printing.

---

Edit according comment:

[image]
*<sup>Image 1: Make sure your class module is named correctly.</sup>*

Comment: its giving me an error "user-defined type not defined" in the second code

Comment: @user4381753 make sure your class module is named `EventClassModule`, see *Image 1*.